# UIViewController view -> loadView vs viewWillAppear

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to free the view of my mainViewController I have on a navigationViewController in order to avoid the memory-warnings that I've been receiving.

The good practice loading the view is in the 'loadview' method, but when I try to dealloc the view (when I go to the next controller of the stack) doing "self.view = nil" it calls again the 'loadview' method so nothing happens.

I solved this problem loading the view in the 'viewWillAppear' method, but, my question is:

Is that procedure correct?
If not (that's what I think) how can I release that view to free its memory?

Which is the best (or more correct) way to do it?

This is the code:

'loadView' without loading the view

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    (some more code)
}
```

The view it is loaded here

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (!pral)
    {
        pral = [[TouchDrawView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
           [self setView:pral];
           [pral release];
    }
        (some more code)
}
```

This is the call to the next viewController of the stack

```
- (void)menus:(id)sender
{
    opcions *ops = [[opcions alloc] init];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:ops animated:YES];
    [ops release];

//Here I'm trying to free memory releasing the view
    [pral removeFromSuperview];
    pral = nil;
    self.view = nil;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better hook to build custom subviews is viewDidLoad.

Minimally, you should free the retained subviews (pre-ARC) in didReceiveMemoryWarning and in dealloc.

No need to release when you push to the new viewController.  Your old one is still there, underneath.

Comment: Yes, my old one is there, but there is no need for it's view to be there as well consuming memory resources, isn't it? (it is not on the screen). So, if I understood well, is a good practice to do nothing and "react" when a memory warning is received?

Comment: It's ok to receive a memory warning (which will trigger viewDidUnload) because until you receive that warning, you've not got a memory problem so there's no need to dispose of stuff. If you dispose of stuff when you don't need to, you potentially create other problems, like needing to reload it all again (= delay) or worse, losing info which is harder to reload (which may have come from its parent VC).

Comment: @SomaMan, yes, that's makes sense. Thanks for all that quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

u don't have to Unload the View because its automatically Unload. u just have to release those object which contain the memory in ViewdidUnload method.

Comment: Yes but, I think that ViewDidUnload is not called (in a simple naviagationController app) unless the view is unloaded due a memory warning. And I was trying to avoid that situation.